# ng-repeat to show each elements individually

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am working on angularjs application.

Please find the demo : http://plnkr.co/edit/77CLq8lB0livmtCXLTKa?p=preview

As shown in the demo for the first 3 div's it is displaying the div values after every 5seconds, similarly i want to show for div calling detailsController which is using ng-repeat. I want to show each element of ng-repeat with 5 seconds delay as shown for first 3 divs.

Below is the sample html code

```
<div ng-controller="MainController" style="width: 100%">
  <div ng-if="show==1">
    11111111111
  </div>

  <div ng-if="show==2">
    2222222222
  </div>

  <div ng-if="show==3">
    333333333
  </div>

  <div ng-if="show==4" ng-controller="detailsController">
    <div ng-repeat="detail in details">
      {{detail.name}} {{$index}} <br> DetailList : {{detailsList}}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

As shown in the demo for first 3 div's it is showing as a slide each with 5 seconds delay.
Similarly i want to show each element in the the list iterating with ng-repeat with 5 seconds delay instead of displaying all the elements in the list as shown in the demo.
Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: In other words, you want to build a carousel that cycles each 5 seconds?

Comment: not exactly..but if you look at first 3 divs, already it is showing the values of each div with 5 seconds delay. The same way i want to show for div4 which is calling detailsController  and using ng-repeat to show the elements.I want to show each element of ng-repeat with 5seconds delay as shown for first 3 divs.@nicooga

Comment: If I understand correctly, you don't need to ng-repeat over your items in order to do this. You could just have a single `div` with an `ng-model` whose value is replaced every 5 seconds on the controller side. This is easy enough using an array and a few calls to set timeout

Comment: @Felipe - I think i should iterate the list in order to show the elements in the array, and so i'm using ng-repeat.Can you modify the plnkr if possible with your suggestion

Comment: @user8727958 this is what I mean http://plnkr.co/edit/8CmjlKVJLLWpmYmV1djR?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

You can check if `show == $index`.

```
<div ng-repeat="detail in details">
   <div ng-if="show==$index">
      {{detail.name}} {{$index}} <br>
      DetailList : {{detailsList}}
   </div>
</div>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/5OvcToWEVFidrDnk9NTo?p=preview

Comment: Please find the updated http://plnkr.co/edit/HaRhHS6RlFc8FudQMoyR?p=preview , it is not working with the scenario mentioned in the demo..@Adriani6

Comment: What scenario? What demo? Your question you posted here is answered ("I want to show each element of ng-repeat with 5 seconds delay as shown for first 3 divs.")

Answer (score 0):

You need to store your `detailsList` variable inside `$rootScope`, then use `{{details[detailsList].name}}` in your template. Update `detailsList` inside the same interval of `MainController`. Do not use two separate intervals for this because they run at the same time, so you don't see the updates.

Here is a working [**plunkr demo**](http://plnkr.co/edit/mAmvZmjXymtDod02fTyO?p=preview).

**index.html**

```
<div ng-if="show==4" ng-controller="detailsController">
    <div>
        {{details[detailsList].name}}
    </div>
</div>
```

**app.js**

```
app.controller('MainController', function($scope,$rootScope, $interval) {
    $scope.show = 1;
    $scope.slide = "sample clise";
    $rootScope.detailsList = 0;

    $interval(function() {
        if ($scope.show === 4) {
            if ($rootScope.detailsList < 2) {
                ++$rootScope.detailsList;
            } else {
                $rootScope.detailsList = 0;
                $scope.show = 1;
            }
        }
        else if ($scope.show < 4) {
            ++$scope.show; 
        } else {
            $scope.show = 1;
        }
    }, 5000, 0);
});
```

Comment: @user8727958 Okay, I understand now. I have edited my answer to correctly answer your problem. I updated my plunkr link to show the proper example. Here is the link again: http://plnkr.co/edit/mAmvZmjXymtDod02fTyO?p=preview

Comment: thanks for the inputs, How to skip the interval showing the empty div if the list size is zero as shown in demo here http://plnkr.co/edit/iF1P2TUIDgezt1Kyzvtp?p=preview .When calling ng-controller="detailsController", the list size is zero so i dont want to show the empty div for 5 seconds, instead move to other div if the current div to show size is zero. Any inputs?